# How to embed animation into ParaView scene from script?

Tags: python, animation, vtk, scene, paraview

So I try to add animation to my scene in paraview using Python. I started with [wiki script](http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/Python/Animation). Animation plays only when `scene.Play()` is called.  While it is playing ParaView (5.0.1 in my case) get stuck with window paying animation - scene can not be rotated while it is playing, buttons cannot be pushed. How to keep editor alive in ParaView animation from script?

Also when I click on editor animation `Play Scene` button nothing is played at all.

I wonder how to embed animation into scene so that it would be playable and savable from ParaView editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That wiki example appears to be a little dated.

Try this in a script instead:

```
# get active source.
sphere1 = GetActiveSource()

# get animation track
sphere1StartThetaTrack = GetAnimationTrack('StartTheta', index=0, proxy=sphere1)

# create keyframes for this animation track

# create a key frame
keyFrame1 = CompositeKeyFrame()

# create a key frame
keyFrame2 = CompositeKeyFrame()
keyFrame2.KeyTime = 1.0
keyFrame2.KeyValues = [360.0]

# initialize the animation track
sphere1StartThetaTrack.KeyFrames = [keyFrame1, keyFrame2]

# get animation scene
animationScene = GetAnimationScene()
animationScene.Play()
```

You should be able to interact with the visualization while the animation runs and start it or stop it with the animation controls.

Note that I used ParaView's Python Trace feature to arrive at this code example.

Comment: BTW is it possible to embed object creation at some time during animation or they shall all be precreated before animation begins?

Comment: I don't know how you would create an object during an animation - best to create them before animating.